# Button activities between pages

Tags: android

how to control the visibility of button present in fragment 2 on the selection of checkboz in fragment 1.

Comment: Hi Abu, can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It will be easier to help you!

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean by pages? Activities or fragments? You cannot directly access UI components of other activity of fragment inside current activity/fragment.

Comment: aktivitiy between

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

So as u said u have a checkbox and button in page 1 and onClick of that button you want to go to page 2 and get the status of the check box.

Assuming that you have two fragments as pages.

Here is a sample code (**Java**) :

```
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.yourBtn);
        CheckBox check = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putBoolean(key, false);
                if(check.isChecked()){
                   bundle.putBoolean(key,true);
                   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }
                getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

Then In the next page(Fragment):

```
       Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        if (bundle.getBoolean(key)== true){
            button2.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;  // button2 is the second button you want to control.
        }
        else {
            button2.setVisibility = View.GONE;
        }
```

**In Kotlin:**

```
  val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.yourBtn);
        val check = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox);
        btn.setOnClickListner{
            val fragment = SecondFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putBoolean(key,false) // setting default value is false it checkbox is checked then it will be overridden.
            if (check.isChecked){
                bundle.putBoolean(key,true)
                fragment.argumnets= bundle
            }
            parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit()
        }
```

Next Page

```
    val bundle = this.arguments

        if (bundle!!.getBoolean(key)) {
            button2.setVisibility =
                View.VISIBLE // button2 is the second button you want to control.
        } else {
            button2.setVisibility = View.GONE
        }
```

**NOTE**: This is a beginner level code so that is easily understandable.

Comment: I hope this helps 